# IIS: Unrecognized attribute 'runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests'

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I am experiencing trouble running a .Net core web application on a specific Windows 2016 server. The same packages is working on other servers running Windows 2016.

### Things done
-Installed all components except CGI in Windows Server (IIS) >>Application Development
-Installed .Net 4.8

Detailed Error Information:
Module
IIS Web Core

Notification
BeginRequest

Handler
Not yet determined

Error Code
0x8007000d

Config Error
Unrecognized attribute 'runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests'

Comment: That’s expected. There is no such a setting with all lower case.

Comment: This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file contains a malformed XML element. You can try to delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file.